# How can I first launch the project with VulcanJS?

Tags: meteor, vulcan, vulcanjs

I've just started to install Vulcan Js on my computer. So I follow the tuto on official website.
And after I execute `npm start`, I've got this error.

```
> npm start

> vulcan-meteor@1.16.1 start
> meteor --settings settings.json

[[[[[ ~/Sites/Vulcan/Vulcan ]]]]]             

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                                                                
W20210326-10:29:14.756(1)? (STDERR) /Users/imac/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.1.0.23f9er.0sbtf++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20210326-10:29:14.872(1)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20210326-10:29:14.873(1)? (STDERR)                         ^
W20210326-10:29:14.873(1)? (STDERR) 
W20210326-10:29:14.873(1)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot read property 'upsert' of undefined
W20210326-10:29:14.873(1)? (STDERR)     at packages/vulcan:accounts/imports/oauth_config.js:8:41
W20210326-10:29:14.874(1)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20210326-10:29:14.874(1)? (STDERR)     at module (packages/vulcan:accounts/imports/oauth_config.js:7:25)
W20210326-10:29:14.874(1)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:336:7)
W20210326-10:29:14.874(1)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:14)
W20210326-10:29:14.875(1)? (STDERR)     at Module.moduleLink [as link] (/Users/imac/.meteor/packages/modules/.0.16.0.3rozyi.4j6sy++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime/index.js:52:22)
W20210326-10:29:14.875(1)? (STDERR)     at module (packages/vulcan:accounts/main_server.js:1:356)
W20210326-10:29:14.875(1)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:336:7)
W20210326-10:29:14.875(1)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:14)
W20210326-10:29:14.876(1)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:258:21)
W20210326-10:29:14.876(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/imac/Sites/Vulcan/Vulcan/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/vulcan_accounts.js:3282:15
W20210326-10:29:14.876(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/imac/Sites/Vulcan/Vulcan/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/vulcan_accounts.js:3287:3
W20210326-10:29:14.876(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/imac/Sites/Vulcan/Vulcan/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:401:38
W20210326-10:29:14.876(1)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20210326-10:29:14.877(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/imac/Sites/Vulcan/Vulcan/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:226:21
W20210326-10:29:14.877(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/imac/Sites/Vulcan/Vulcan/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:464:7
W20210326-10:29:14.877(1)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (/Users/imac/Sites/Vulcan/Vulcan/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:280:14)
W20210326-10:29:14.877(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/imac/Sites/Vulcan/Vulcan/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:463:13
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

I don't know what to do.

Follow my config:
Meteor version : 2.1
NPM version : 7.7.4
Vulcan git branch : devel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you follow the steps of installation as specified:

1. Install node and npm - I prefer to use [n](https://github.com/tj/n#installation)

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tj/n/master/bin/n -o n
bash n lts
```

2. Install Meteor

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

3. Clone the starter repo

```
git clone https://github.com/VulcanJS/Vulcan-Starter && cd Vulcan-Starter
```

4. Rename `simple_settings.json` to `settings.json`

```
mv sample_settings.json settings.json
```

5. Install npm packages

```
meteor npm install
```

6. Start the application

```
meteor npm start
```

Your app should be working at `http://localhost:3000/`